# how do you get the path of the javascript file run through the rhino shell commandline

Tags: javascript, rhino

how do you get the path of the javascript file run through the rhino shell commandline?

eg: java -jar js.jar /path/to/this/file.js

i would like to get `/path/to/this/file.js`, any ideas?

Comment: is it possible to use the java namespace to access the full `java -jar js.jar /path/to/this/file.js` entered at the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is possible without some Java.
jsdoc solves it by using a class that wraps rhino and inserts said path (though its a bit buggy). You can find its code (and a shell script that runs it is in the trunk): http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/jsdoc-toolkit/java/src/JsRun.java

Comment: Youre welcome. I just remembered why I thought it was buggy. To run without optimizations (and therefore have line numbers in stack traces), I had to run:
java -jar lib/jsdoc/jsrun.jar -opt -1 lib/run.js
And in that scenario, jsrun.jar would consider "-opt" the path.